# Trouble Parsing Json with JArray.Parse

Tags: c#, json

I think I am missing something obvious here.

I get a `json` response back from a service and then format it so that I can work with it as a `JArray`.

My formatting code leaves me with what I think is needed to use `Jarray.Parse`.

If I seep through this `C#` code, I can see that the value of my `json` now looks looks like:

```
[
 {\"Id\":\"row1\",\"TheDate\":\"01/01/2013 00:00:00\",\"Description\":\"Test1\",\"Field\":\"N\"},       
 {\"Id\":\"row2\",\"TheDate\":\"01/01/2013 00:00:00\",\"Description\":\"Test2\",\"Field\":\"N\"}
]
```

I then call `JArray.Parse(json)` and I get the following error:

`Invalid property identifier character: \. Path '[0]', line 1, position 2.`

Strangely enough, If I call:

```
 JArray.Parse("[
      {\"Id\":\"row1\",\"TheDate\":\"01/01/2013 00:00:00\",\"Description\":\"Test1\",\"Field\":\"N\"},      
      {\"Id\":\"row2\",\"TheDate\":\"01/01/2013 00:00:00\",\"Description\":\"Test2\",\"Field\":\"N\"}
     ]")
```

which is the exact same string as the value taken from the debugger, it all works fine.

What have I missed?

Comment: are you using $.ajax method for the getting response ?

Comment: @Mac - no, the response is what I've posted.  The error is with parsing it.

Comment: try adding `@`: JArray.Parse(@json)

Comment: @Artyom, thanks, didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put a `\"` in a string this information is convert to `"` char. This conversion happens at compile time, the compiler interprets the slash '\' as a command and not as a character. But the problem it's in your case the slash is still in your string.

Try something like this:

```
string json = @"[
    {'Id':'row1','TheDate':'01/01/2013 00:00:00','Description':'Test1','Field':'N'},
    {'Id':'row2','TheDate':'01/01/2013 00:00:00','Description':'Test2','Field':'N'}
]".Replace("'", "\"");

JArray.Parse(json);
```

In your code if you use a multiline string the compiler will not consider slash as special character. This is the same as setting the at sign in front of the first quotes like this:

```
var test = @"\a\b\c\\\n";
```

Comment: I did in the following way: var strJson = @"" + jsonContent; JArray.Parse(strJson); Now is working perfectly thanks!